# C# Interface Inheritance override

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I confused about a base interface property hiding, what is still needed in the implemented class, can somebody tell me why?

The goal will be the 'EndClass' only hide/override the 'IClassValue Value', and not need to implement the already hide 'IBaseClassValue Value'.

Thanks!

```
public interface IBaseClassValue { }

public interface IClassValue : IBaseClassValue { }

public class ClassValue : IClassValue { }

//-----------------------------------------

public interface IEndClassBase
{
    IBaseClassValue Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IEndClassBaseChild : IEndClassBase
{
    new IClassValue Value { get; set; }
}

//-----------------------------------------

public abstract class EndClassAbs<TValue>
{
    TValue Value { get; set; }
}

public class EndClass : EndClassAbs<ClassValue>, IEndClassBaseChild
{
    public new IClassValue Value { get; set; }

    //IBaseClassValue IEndClassBase.Value { get; set; } //-> Why need here the base member while already hide in the 'IEndClassBaseChild' interface
}
```

Comment: Because you can always cast to the base interface and by this access the property in the base interface.

Comment: EndClass is doing multiple inheritance - one parent is a typed abstract class, another is interface. so, your `EndClass` need to implement IEndClassBaseChild.IBaseClassValue.Value too.

Answer (score 0):

If I use somekind of shadow class '_EndClass' then inherit from it, the 'EndClass' could hide/override the 'ClassValue'. I still don't know why this can not do in one step.

```
public class _EndClass : EndClassAbs<ClassValue>, IEndClassBase
{
    public new IBaseClassValue Value { get; set; }
}

public class EndClass : _EndClass, IEndClassBaseChild
{
    public new IClassValue Value { get; set; }
}
```